# Bulk insert in Couchbase using .NET SDK

Tags: .net, nosql, bulkinsert, couchbase, bulk-load

Im trying to bulk insert into couchbase using the .NET SDK (1.3) but can't find the right syntax.
In the SDK documentation under "troubleshooting" it refers to a problem that may occure when "bulk loading". This make me believe it's possible somehow.

I'll be glad for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware bulk loading isn't supported via the SDK for .NET (it isn't for Java so I'll assume they are 99% the same).

However they do have a tool for bulk loading in json called the cbdocloader tool.  This allows you to bulk load in json to a specific node and bucket of Couchbase.  There is an official blog post covering the use of it:

http://blog.couchbase.com/loading-json-data-couchbase

Option 2:

You can always just use the standard set method, iterate over wherever your documents are (I'm assuming they are on the file system) and set each one individually.